# Forcing Pandas to accept a no-op command

Tags: python, pandas

I need to use a no-op operation on a pandas column.
Using the following does not work. Any idea why?

```
df['flag'] = filtered.map(lambda x: 'N' if x else pass)
```

Comment: Do you want to skip the row or preserve the original value? If you wanted to preserve the value then you could just do `df['flag'] = filtered.map(lambda x: 'N' if x else x)`

Comment: Otherwise you could just filter the NaN (I'm assuming that is what you want to do, difficult to tell without sample data and code) and apply the map: `df['flag'] = filtered.notnull().map('N')`

Answer (score 4):

Your syntax is invalid. `pass` is a [statement](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-pass-statement) and you cannot use it in a conditional expression and in many other contexts. See:

```
>>> True if False else pass # inappropriate use
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    True if False else pass
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

>>> if pass: # inappropriate use
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    if pass:
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

>>> set(pass) # inappropriate use
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    set(pass)
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

>>> a = [ pass ] # inappropriate use
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    a = [ pass ]
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

>>> def lazy_function(): # good use
...    pass
...
```

In your code try returning empty string instead (or any other value):

```
df['flag'] = filtered.map(lambda x: 'N' if x else '')
```

Comment: +1. As an alternative, you could use `numpy.nan` as the filler value. *Might* be more convenient down the road.